# Create custom image gallery in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have used below code to pick photo from gallery or directly using camera

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
         clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = 
      [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        photoButtonNum=0;
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController 
                           animated:YES 
                         completion:nil];
        imagePickerController.sourceType =  
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        photoButtonNum=1;
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController 
                           animated:YES 
                         completion:nil];
        imagePickerController.sourceType =  
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
}
```

i am looking to create a custom directory(folder) of my own application to save the picked photos in iPhone. I need your help to

1. create a custom directory of my own app
2. want to save the picked photo in that custom directory.

I am a new guy in `iPhone` development, so waiting for your valuable help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is helpful for you to create and save [Photo in your Directory](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/)

And Also you can use following code.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
          didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
     UIImage *pickedImage = 
       [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage);

     NSString *documentsDirectory = 
       [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                            NSUserDomainMask, 
                                            YES) lastObject];
     NSString *path = [documentsDirectory 
       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imageName.png"];

    NSError * error = nil;
    [imageData writeToFile:storePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

    if (error != nil) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is 'storePath' here? is it 'path' itself?

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5 give you the feature to add a custom photo album using [**`ALAssetsLibrary`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722)

Here is a tutorial [**iOS5: Saving photos in custom photo album**](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/)

---

**Edit**

In case link becomes inactive

Create ivar in .h file

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library;
```

Then in your code probably in `viewDidLoad`

```
library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
```

Then in your delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [self.library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"Touch Code Magazine" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: @SamBudda it's all right, though I have edited my answer in case the link becomes inactive. Also giving links in answers is not advised on SO. Whenever I came across my answer which contains only links (which were posted in my initial career of SO) I edit them